# Is there a standard way to structure a website

Tags: web-development, html, css

When I first taught myself how to make websites (html/css) I used exact pixel width and height for all div elements. I've also practiced making websites with nothing but percentage width and height.

I can use either technique fairly easily, but I wanted to know is there a standard technique or structure to building the basic layout of a website?

My recent favorite is to make my main div container an exact pixel width with auto height (centered on the page) and then have all divs inside set to a percentage width and auto height. This works just fine for me, but if there's a widely acknowledged standard to making a website from scratch I would love to know.

Comment: not a programming question. should move to stackoverflow

Comment: Keeping this as a comment because its not really my area.  What seems common now is using scaffolding such as Twitter Bootstrap, and a '12 column' layout (where widths are given not in pixels or percentages, but the number of columns out of 12 they span).

Comment: This is a programming question as I am writing code that makes up a website -- this would not be a stack-overflow question.

Comment: I think the trend now with mobile is viewport size, ems, and breakpoints.

Comment: Agree with @ThisBetterWork this is moer about best practise than about a specific technique or technology.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Thank you for your suggestions, I have heard of the 960 and 12 column grid layouts and will check out twitter bootstrap.

Comment: And 960 has fallen out of favor for a while now which is why I agree this question is too broad and too much design opinion. 12 columns, too, is an opinion and doesn't work in all cases. Neither work well in a responsive design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As GrandMasterB mentioned, the current **trend** is to use scaffolding and responsive column-based layouts that make it much easier to write web applications for multiple target environments all at the same time: PCs, tablets, smartphones.

The most used is [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)... to the point where you can almost instantly recognize a website using it. To the point where a [blog post](http://css.dzone.com/articles/please-stop-using-twitter) has been written to stop using it... And as such, a lot of websites with Bootstrap themes (free or/and premium) have popped out of nowhere such as [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) for example.

The other one that I've personnally used is [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which is also nice and offers the same gric/column based layout. Similarly to Bootstrap, you can customize the CSS and Javascript components included before downloading the source files.

I don't know if this trend is going to stop or if it will fall into "another way of writing web apps", but there are many pros while working with such frameworks:

- Part of the responsive design is already done for you (and if you don't do too much complicated stuff, that part is going to be very close to 100%)
- It's easy to pick up (for exmaple: most important CSS classes in Bootstrap: `row`, and `spanx` where *x* is a number between 1 and 12)
- It's easily customizable with additional fonts, icons, theme colors
- It's pretty !
- You save a lot of time for more important stuff rather than micro-managing pixel by pixel all your DOM elements (you can still do that, sure, but if you do things well, you should not have to)
- They come with JQuery-based components
- It's still being worked on, and updated with modern CSS3 and HTML5 features while keeping compatibility with older browsers
- It's incredibly easy to integrate Bootstrap to a MVVM framework such as KnockoutJS for example.

And last but not least... **Both Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation have excellent documentations**

Edit: found [a website comparing](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php) Bootstrap to Zurb Foundation and to another one that I didn't knew of, [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) (still grid/column based): http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php

Comment: Thank you for this information! I made a quick twitter bootstrap website and can definitely see all the benefits you mentioned. 
Although, it worries me a little to think that hand crafted sites may not be necessary anymore.

Comment: @ThisBetterWork Thanks, I totally understand that feeling :-) It's very useful to have deep knowledge of CSS 2/3, but now that I know  Bootstrap very well, I really don't see myself getting back doing things the long way. I however am happy to be quickly able to jump into important stuff.